# How do I publish events with ruby event_store_client?

Tags: ruby, grpc, eventstoredb

I'm following the documentation on [event_store_client](https://github.com/yousty/event_store_client) in order to set up a pub/sub system using [EventStore DB](https://www.eventstore.com/) but I can't get the events to publish.

Here are the steps I took so far:

- I initially tried to set up the server as a Docker container in insecure mode: the server boots, I can get to the admin UI (without authentication) but then the client fails by trying to connect with SSL and I haven't found a way to disable security on the client side.
- I then tried to start the server using the script provided in the gem, but something goes wrong around docker-sync and the server doesn't boot.
- Finally, I replicated the steps in the script, creating self-signed certificates, and I can get the server to boot and the client to connect securely using the preferred gRPC protocol.

I am able to follow the tutorial steps up to

```rb
event_store.publish(stream: 'newstream', events: [event])
```

and then I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/event_store_client-1.0.8/lib/event_store_client/event.rb:17:in `initialize'
```

I tried to look in the source code following the stack trace, but I can't find what's wrong with that call. The `event` object seems initialized correctly, and I'm pretty sure the connection is established correctly as well (I get another error with different credentials).

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `event_store_client` isn't compatible with Ruby 3.0.0 as of version 1.0.8. The problem *may* be caused by the dependency on `dry-struct` 1.4.0, or by the way the attributes are passed when an `EventStoreClient::Event` is initialized.

For now I'll stick to using Ruby 2.7.3, with which the examples do work as documented, and update this Q&A once I eventually upgrade to Ruby 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the latest version(2.x) of `event_store_client`. It supports ruby 3+. The event could be published like follows:

```rb
EventStoreClient.client.append_to_stream(stream_name, event)
```

You could check the docs [here](https://github.com/yousty/event_store_client/blob/master/docs/appending_events.md)